# ¿Cómo arreglar validación de una página con HTML,JS,CSS?

Tags: javascript, html

Intenté que chat GPT me lo arreglara o me dijera como pero las soluciones que daba no quedaron en lo que quería.
Si bien valida, no está haciéndolo completamente. Necesito que valide que todos los campos contengan texto, está haciéndolo solo con el "@"

```js
//Ejecutando funciones
document.getElementById("btn__iniciar-sesion").addEventListener("click", iniciarSesion);
document.getElementById("btn__registrarse").addEventListener("click", register);
window.addEventListener("resize", anchoPage);

//Declarando variables
var formulario_login = document.querySelector(".formulario__login");
var formulario_register = document.querySelector(".formulario__register");
var contenedor_login_register = document.querySelector(".contenedor__login-register");
var caja_trasera_login = document.querySelector(".caja__trasera-login");
var caja_trasera_register = document.querySelector(".caja__trasera-register");

//FUNCIONES

function anchoPage() {

  if (window.innerWidth > 850) {
    caja_trasera_register.style.display = "block";
    caja_trasera_login.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    caja_trasera_register.style.display = "block";
    caja_trasera_register.style.opacity = "1";
    caja_trasera_login.style.display = "none";
    formulario_login.style.display = "block";
    contenedor_login_register.style.left = "0px";
    formulario_register.style.display = "none";
  }
}

anchoPage();


function iniciarSesion() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 850) {
    formulario_login.style.display = "block";
    contenedor_login_register.style.left = "10px";
    formulario_register.style.display = "none";
    caja_trasera_register.style.opacity = "1";
    caja_trasera_login.style.opacity = "0";
  } else {
    formulario_login.style.display = "block";
    contenedor_login_register.style.left = "0px";
    formulario_register.style.display = "none";
    caja_trasera_register.style.display = "block";
    caja_trasera_login.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function register() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 850) {
    formulario_register.style.display = "block";
    contenedor_login_register.style.left = "410px";
    formulario_login.style.display = "none";
    caja_trasera_register.style.opacity = "0";
    caja_trasera_login.style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    formulario_register.style.display = "block";
    contenedor_login_register.style.left = "0px";
    formulario_login.style.display = "none";
    caja_trasera_register.style.display = "none";
    caja_trasera_login.style.display = "block";
    caja_trasera_login.style.opacity = "1";
  }
}
document.getElementById("Ventiladorgira").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("rotate");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4fc6f7b4b3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <img src="AEROLITE.png" alt="Logotipo de la tienda">
  <nav>
    <div class="menu-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="catalogo.html">Catalogo</a></li>
        <li><a href="formulario.html">Formulario</a></li>
        <li><a href="recomendaciones.html">Recomendaciones</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a href="login.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Iniciar sesión</button></a>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>
<div class="content">

  <h1 class="logo"> Contacto <span></span></h1>

  <div class="contact-wrapper animated bounceInUp">
    <div class="contact-form">
      <h3>Contacto </h3>
      <form action="">
        <p>
          <label>Nombre Completo</label>
          <input type="text" name="fullname">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Correo Electronico</label>
          <input type="email" name="email">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Número</label>
          <input type="tel" name="phone">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Asunto</label>
          <input type="text" name="affair">
        </p>
        <p class="block">
          <label>Mensaje</label>
          <textarea name="message" rows="3"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p class="block">
          <button>
                            Enviar
                        </button>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-info">
      <h4>Más Info</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Baker Street</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> (111) 111 111 111</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i> contact@website.com</li>
      </ul>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero provident ipsam necessitatibus repellendus?</p>
      <p>Company.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor, te invito a leer [ask] y luego darle [edit] a tu pregunta para completarla. Un saludo.

Comment: Si un campo contiene texto (cualquiera sea} es valido, caso contrario es invalido....eso? Además debes agregar un [MRE] dentro del sitio, no se valen enlaces externos, aun que lo puedes dejar como apoyo

Comment: Si, se trata de la validación de un formulario, donde el usuario puede dejar un mensaje, pero cada campo debe estar completo y no vacío, es decir; debe tener nombre, asunto, mensaje, numero de contacto, correo, etc... lo que está pasando que solo está validadando el "@" del correo electrónico, una vez pone el "@" ya se puede enviar el formulario y eso no debe pasar xd. @Yussef

Comment: @MAURICIOIGNACIOGUZMANAGUIRR Pero en el código que has puesto no veo algún intento de validación, veo solo código para elementos estéticos. Por otro lado, por qué no ocupas la validación que ya tiene HTML?

Comment: Buen día amigo, necesitas que los campos contengan únicamente texto o simplemente que no estén vacíos?